# How to start the runnable immediately using handlers

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, handlers

How can we start the runnable immediately instead of adding the runnable to the message queue....can we do that...?

What I observe is that the post method is having some delay in executing.

Answer (score 0):

In Android post executes on the main thread, so the Runnable is added to the message queue and then processed.

You could create your own [ExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and submit your Runnables directly to it, and it will use a thread pool to execute whatever Runnables you submit, should be no real lag between submit() and when the Runnable starts running.   These will not run on the main UI thread, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Alex,I have a scenario wherein I need to update the UI simultaneously with the mediaplayer song.

Comment: Depending on the amount of work you are doing in this runnable, you may be able to break up the work from the interaction with the UI.  When posting a runnable to the UI make it really small and update 1 thing, do the rest of the work on a Runnable in the ExecutorService.

Comment: I recommend using AsyncTask in that case. Would probably need some refactoring, though.